# Commerce - Product Type Best Practices, Blank Fields

Tags: commerce

Is there a best practice for when you should create new product types versus adding more fields to existing product types? Lets say you sell a bunch of different types of clothing, one of them being shirts. Say some shirts have specific fields like arm length, collar type, etc. and others just have generic fields like Size, Color, etc. Would it be best to have a generic product type called shirts and have EVERY possible shirt field on it, then just leave fields blank that dont apply when adding shirt products? Or, would it be best to have specific product types with ONLY the fields you would fill out for that specific product (which would mean the site could have a ton of different product types...long t-shirts, short t-shirts, collar shirts, long pants, short pants, etc).

I am having a hard time figuring out how to structure my products on the site im building (which involves many types of scientific instruments and industrial products). Some product types use the same fields but then have a few extra fields that not all products would use.

Is there a performance hit on having a generalized product type that has about 20 fields, or does it only really affect usability as far as how products are added to the site?